# i tried to re-install same package apk , it gave me error invalid apk file how to update it

Tags: android, apk, adb

i tried to re-install same package apk 
with

```
adb install -r myapp-release.apk
```

But it gave me error :

> invalid apk file

how to update it.

Comment: can you provide full error message?

Comment: I think in both apk file certificate is different please manually un-install old apk from device and then install new one.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error if the file is not found, so you're likely just in the wrong directory.